# Transaction mined but execution failed

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, constructor, binance-smart-chain, failed-transaction

I was trying to deploy my smart contract to BSC testnet using Remix IDE,although it compiles successfully but when I try to deploy it I get this error message.

"false Transaction mined but the execution failed"

This is my [transaction](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xc79dcbbcf85a8cc5a2cfadc648fdf9395327af1c1af4f72ea4203b4ac6f66007)

You can see in full my sc [here](https://gist.github.com/cuongvu694/bc733dc5c6f8f7326af18c002ccd589b)
[image]

Thank you for your time

Comment: can you tell me which function try call and get this error?

Comment: out of gas. you need to send more gas (you currently send 300000)

Comment: @AkshayTarpara Hello there, I tried to call the contract Safuu but it failed many times.

Comment: @MajdTL I tried to call at 800000 but it still failed. Would you mind to try on remix. The contract name Safuu